# Unable to connect to local database in Visual Studio 2012 express For Web: (error 26)(C#)(SQL Server 2012)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

Recently, I've made a simple website with a database (in an App_Data folder). I made a class file (in an App_Code folder) with the following method that will create a connection to the database:

```
public static SqlConnection ConnectToDb(string dbFileName)
{
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/");
    path += dbFileName;
    string connString =  @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + 
                         path + 
                         ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    return conn;

}
```

When I need to open that connection, I get the following message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

What I don't understand is that I used the -same- method in another website that I built over a year ago in Visual Studio 2010, where it worked fine.

I checked the path and it was correct, same with the database file name in the parameters.

What is wrong with the code or with VS's settings? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just tried to use `(localDB)\v11.0` instead of `.\SQLEXPRESS`
and now I get this error message:

> The user instance login flag is not allowed when connecting to a user instance of SQL Server.

Comment: Your server address may be incorrect or it's busy.

Comment: Found the solution, had to set User Instance as false. I'd post the answer but I'm not permitted to yet because of low reputation.

Comment: Good, you can post the answer as an Update part in your question. You can come back and answer later when you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because the `(localDB)\v11.0` is already a user instance of SQL Server. When you were using the `SQLEXPRESS` SQL Server instance, well, it's not. So, just get rid of the `User Instance=true` on the connection string.